# C# Web Forms table in Repeater. Identify and hide element on button click

Tags: c#, webforms

This is my code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Handset_Repeater" runat="server">  
         <HeaderTemplate>
             <table>
                 <tr>                     
                     <th>MAC ID ADDRESS</th>
                     <th>MODEL NUMBER</th>
                 </tr>
         </HeaderTemplate>       
         <ItemTemplate> 
            <tr>               
               <%-- <td style="visibility:hidden"><%#Eval("EID")%></td>--%>
                <td><%#Eval("MacIdAddress")%></td>
                <td><%#Eval("Model")%></td>  
                <td> <asp:Button runat="server" ID="MagicButton" Text="Delete" OnClick="MagicButton_Click"/></td>                    
            </tr>                 
         </ItemTemplate>
             <FooterTemplate>
                 </table>
             </FooterTemplate>
     </asp:Repeater>
```

As you can see, I've commented line with `<%#Eval("EID")%>`. I can add it to my table. I need to hide `table row` on button click (or remove from the table) and send `EID` to the event handler:

```
protected void MagicButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Can anyone help me? Is exist any way to do it in web forms?

Answer (score 1):

Change the hidden field to an asp control:

```
<td><asp:HiddenField ID="eidFLD" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("EID") %>'/></td>
```

then in the click:

```
protected void MagicButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button magicBTN = sender as Button;
    string eid = (magicBTN.NamingContainer.FindControl("eidFLD") as HiddenField).Value;
    //do something with eid here 
}
```